# Function exercise check-up

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, proof-verification, prime-numbers

I want to make sure I did everything correctly, so here's the exercise:

> Given $P$ the set of positive prime numbers and be $S = \mathbb N^* - \{1\}$. $\forall n \in S,\ \pi(n)$ is the set of the primes $\in P$ which divide $n$, $\ \ p_n = \min\ \pi(n)$, $\ \ q_n = \max\ \pi(n)$. Given also the application: $$f: n \in S \longrightarrow (p_n, q_n) \in P \times P$$
>   $\rho$ is the following relation order defined on $S$: $$\forall n, m \in S, n\  \rho\ m \iff n = m \text{ or } (p_n\mid p_m\text{ and } q_n < q_m).$$

**Questions**:

1. Is $f$ injective? Is $f$ surjective?
2. What is $f(S)$?
3. Determine in $(S, \rho)$ minimum, maximum, minimals and maximals.
4. Is $(S, \rho)$ a lattice?

**My answers**:

1. $f$ is **NOT injective** because $f(2) = f(4) = (2,2)$ but $2 \neq 4$. 
   $f$ is **NOT surjective** because $\not\exists n \in S: f(n) = (3,2)$
2. $f(S) = \{(p, q) \in P \times P: p \leq q\}$
3. There are **no minimals** and no minimum because the minimum of prime numbers is 2 and this number divides only even numbers and surely NOT all the primes.
   There are **no maximals** and no minimum because a prime that can be divided by every prime does NOT exist.
4. $(S, \rho)$ is **not a lattice** because $\not\exists \inf\{2,3\}$

I really appreciate if any of you can correct me if I'm wrong or not about these replies. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1),(2)**: Correct, but you didn't prove (2). If you claim that $Im_f(S)$ is a set $T$, then you must show that indeed $f$ maps everything in $S$ into $T$, and conversely everything in $T$ is the image of something in $S$ under $f$.

**(3)**: You have the right idea for minimum and maximum, but your reasoning is totally flawed for minimal and maximal. Minimal means that there is no smaller. You didn't at all prove that there is no minimal element in $S$. In fact, can you find anything in $S$ that is $ρ$-smaller than $2$? Same for maximal elements.

**(4)**: Correct, but you should justify it by saying that there isn't a prime that divides both $p_2$ and $p_3$.

Comment: Is it true that for (3) there is no minimals (and no minimum) and no maximals (and no maximum)? (4): why doesn't it make sense? $(S, \rho)$ is a lattice $\iff \forall a, b \in S, \exists inf\{a,b\}$ and $\exists \sup\{a,b\}$

Comment: @user1365914: (3) Answer my question first. (4) Oh I read your answer as having something to do with "in $f$". Sorry let me think about it.

Comment: (3) I don't think there is anything in $S$ that is $\rho$-smaller than 2. It could've been $1$ but it is excluded from $S$ and it is not a prime.

Comment: @user1365914: So if there is nothing in $S$ that is $ρ$-smaller than $2$, then $2$ **is in fact minimal** in $S$. Can you find any others?

Comment: Ouch, you're right. Maybe all prime numbers are minimal? What about maximals? I don't think there is any. (and no maximum too)